# Show that $F(s) = \log \zeta(s) + G(s)$ holds for $\text{Re }s>1$ and $F(s)$ does not have a meromorphic continuation for $\text{Re }s<1$.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

**Question**

Let $F(s) = \sum_{p^k} p^{-ks}$, where the summation runs over all prime powers. Show that
$F(s) = \log \zeta(s) + G(s)$ holds for $\text{Re }s>1$, where $G(s)$ is analytic in the half-plane $\text{Re }s > 1/2$. Deduce from this that the function $F(s)$ does not have a meromorphic continuation for $\text{Re }s<1$.

**My Attempt**

I know that $$F(s) = \sum_{p} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p^{ks}} = \sum_{p} \frac{p^{-s}}{1-p^{-s}}\, ,$$ and
$$\log \zeta(s) = \log \left(\prod_{p} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\right) = \sum_{p} \log \left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1} = \sum_{p} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k\, p^{ks}}.$$

But how to proceed naturally, instead of reverse engineering as I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

$$G(s)= \sum_p \sum_{k\ge 2} p^{-sk} (1-1/k)$$ converges absolutely (bounded by $2\zeta(2\Re(s))$) thus is analytic for $\Re(s) > 1/2$ and $$F(s) = \log \zeta(s)+G(s)= -\log (s-1)+ \log ((s-1)\zeta(s))+G(s)$$ has a branch point at $s=1$

Comment: Great answer. But does this question not involve some reverse engineering to find the value of $G(s)$?

Comment: Not sure of what you mean, if we care of $\zeta(s)=\sum_n n^{-s}$ it is because while given by a simple expression $\log \zeta(s)=\sum_{p^k} p^{-sk}/k$ is a generating series of the primes (powers)

Comment: So combining your what you and I have, would that give a rigorous proof?

Comment: For $\Re(s) > 1$, $F(s) =-\log (s-1)+ \log ((s-1)\zeta(s))+G(s)$ and $ \log ((s-1)\zeta(s))+G(s)$ has an analytic continuation to an open containing $\{1\} \cup \Re(s)>1$, since $\log (s-1)$ has a branch point at $s=1$ then so would have a continuation of $F(s)$.

Comment: Just to make sure, what exact theorem are you using to conclude that $G(s)$ is analytic?

Comment: The same one showing that $\zeta(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > 1$, either that it converges locally uniformly (Morera's theorem) or that it is holomorphic (Cauchy integral formula), by comparison with $2\zeta(2 \Re(s))$ and $-4\zeta'(2 \Re(s))$